# NoReverseMatch Reverse for 'profile_user' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django

Views.py

```
@login_required

def profile_edit(request):

    profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=profile)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        return redirect('profile_user')

    context = {
        "title": 'Edit Profile',
        "form":form,
    }
    return render(request, 'profiles/userprofile_form.html', context)
```

main url there is no name space given and profile url is as follows.

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)$', profile_view, name='profile_user'),
```

Could anybody help to solve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL requires a named argument `username`. You have to give it to `redirect()` as keyword argument. Example:

```
redirect('view-name', username='joe')
```

Comment: I changed it to ('profile_user', username=request.user.username) and it works, thank you so much for reply

Answer (score 0):

Your url requires 1 parameter for username. But in `reverse()` you are not passing any parameter. Hence the error. Change the reverse call as

```
return redirect('profile_user', args=(instance.user.username,))
```

Comment: That give me the same error, so I changed it to ('profile_user', username=request.user.username) and it works, thank you so much for reply